# How to properly position edge labels on the edges of graph using networkx?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph, networkx

I have written a code to create a graph from csv file as below

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("pracmap.csv")
g = nx.Graph()
Vlandict = {}
for idx, e in df.iterrows():
    edge_list = []
    EL={}
    ctr = 1
    for dev in ['DEVICE1', 'DEVICE3', 'DEVICE4', 'DEVICE2']:
        # print(e[dev])
        if e[dev] == "NONE":
            continue
        edge_list.append(e[dev])
        # print(edge_list)

        if ctr == 2:
            unode = edge_list[0]
            vnode = edge_list[1]
            Vlandict[(unode, vnode)] = e['VLAN']
            edge_list.reverse()
            edge_list.pop()

        else:
            ctr = ctr +1
print(g.nodes)
pos = nx.spring_layout(g, k=0.5, iterations=20)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(g, pos, edge_labels=Vlandict, font_color='green',label_pos=0.5, rotate=False, font_size=8)
nx.draw(g, with_labels=1,node_shape="s",bbox=dict(facecolor="orange", edgecolor='black', boxstyle='round,pad=0.2'))
plt.savefig("pracmappp.png", format="PNG")
plt.show()
```

This kind of image i am getting where my edge labels are not positioned properly. I want to position these edges labels on edges:
[image: click here to see the image]

[link for csv file](https://github.com/Sabby2337/csv-file-for-pracmapp/blob/main/pracmap.csv)

[this is the csv file i was using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhqXg.jpg)

Comment: Can you supply a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? This would help us to answer your question and narrow down the number of causes.

Comment: I have edited the code to the bare minimum and removed the unnecessary stuff.Basically if you see the labels above edges are flying and i want to position them on the edges and align them.Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: The problem is that we don't have the csv/data and probably stuff like the pandas data frame has no effect on the plotting issue.

Comment: Please don't post images of code/data/error messages. Post the text directly here on SO and specify whether this is a problem of the displayed figure, the stored figure, or both. Also, I suggest reading [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: i have added my code my result figure where my edge labels are not placed properly on the edges (its  the problem) and has also added link to csv file.Can you please help me in positioning or aligning the edge labels correctly on edges

Comment: The spacing between edges is still very less and every time it is making random shape graph.I would be highly thankful to you if you can suggest me how to increase spacing between edges and make my graph more readable

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
nx.draw(g, with_labels=1,node_shape="s",bbox=dict(facecolor="orange", edgecolor='black', boxstyle='round,pad=0.2'))
```

use

```
nx.draw(g, pos=pos, with_labels=1,node_shape="s",bbox=dict(facecolor="orange", edgecolor='black', boxstyle='round,pad=0.2'))
```

Comment: It has helped me in positioning the labels correctly on the edges but the spacing between edges is still very less and every time it is making random shape graph.I would be highly thankful to you if you can suggest me how to increase spacing between edges and make my graph more readable